# How to back-up photos on 2 external hard drives and retain photo creation date?

Tags: file-management, storage, file-transfer, backup, windows-10

As shown in the set-up diagram below, I would like to offload photos from an external hard drive A to external hard drive B so that if one fails, they're not all lost, since all moved photos aren't kept on the laptop.

[image]

1. Any recommendations when backing up photos simultaneously to two
   hard drives, or a better storage process altogether? Especially
   given that moving files between external hard drives (HDD) is
   probably much slower than moving between an HDD and a laptop, given
   that the HDD A is probably temporarily transferring to the laptop
   *and then to* HDD B (2 transfers)
2. How to go about this while making sure that each **photo's creation
   date** in Windows 10 isn't replaced with the date that the file
   transfer was conducted as what some Windows operations do?

Comment: On Windows creation date and modification date are two different things. Creation applies to the container, modification to the contents. Thus the creation date is technically when a file appears on the drive, and if you copy a file to another drive, the creation date on the new drive is the date when the file was copied, but the modification date is the same as the original. For pictures these are totally unimportant, what really counts is the date set in the Exif data.

Comment: Don't confuse file creation date with image creation date. You can't preserve the file creation date when you copy a file. The new file will have a file creation date of the time the file was copied to the new drive. The image creation date is contained inside the image's EXIF information, and remains unchanged when copied.

Comment: @MichaelC are you contradicting what xenoid said? Who is your comment directed to

Comment: @user610620 My comment is directed at the O.P., not the previous comment. (Attempts to use the "at" functionality to address the O.P. doesn't work in the comment section below a question until the O.P. has made a comment themselves.)

Answer (score 1):

The standard copy operation in Windows preserve the filename attributes as file creation date and so on. Which mean you are OK about this.

About copy you can check [`robocopy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) tool which have some advantages over standard copy operation as multi-thread, resume and so on. And you can run two copies to copy simultaneously to the external disks.

P.S. Maybe will be better to ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Software recommendations is definitely a good shout.